# GCP sevice account issue with pub/sub and firebase in spring boot

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-pubsub

In our application we are use 2 different service accounts one for firebase and one for pub/sub.

But when I used to run application I am facing this issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA9w4.png

How can we fix this?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal POM and your `SecurityConfig` class so that we can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: Do not use images for text. Copy and Paste the text into your question.

Comment: Why do you need to use 2 service accounts?